# PMD ParseException

Tags: html, jsp, web, pmd

by analyzing the following code in jsp PMD Rule Designer

```
<HTML> <BODY>
<P class="MajorHeading">Some text</P>
<a title="test" class="all-remarks-link" href="<c:url value="/home/contract/test-result.html?   wr=${param.wr}&amp;test=${testResult.test.id}"/>" target="_blank">
todo
</a>
</BODY> </HTML>
```

I get the following error

ParseException : Encountered " ...Was expecting one of ..">"..."/>".. (at  ligne 3 column 63 )

thanks for your help.